# Flash player passing values from url as GET method

Tags: actionscript-3, actionscript, flash

I am making a audio flash player which will play a sound passed to it.

How can i pass the values from a browser url?

like i have to write

```
http://domain/folder1/folder2/player.swf?file=http://domain/folder1/folder3/mymp3file.mp3
```

in browser and swf will parse it to play the file from the location passed as GET parameter 'file'. How i can do it in as i am using Adobe Flash CS4 Professional with actionscript 3.0

Any help or idea or link to this will be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the embed tag that flash generates (which puts the player into your page) has a param called flashvars that you can pass whatever arguments you want to, and then collect them within the movie from root.environment.

So... it's a 3 step process

1) grab the variable from the query string with javascript...

```
var myVal = document.location.query.substring(1);//this removes the '?'from the front
```

then follow the directions in the link below for the last 2 steps.

2) write it with javascript into the flashvars param of the embed tag in the html

3) collect and use the variable inside of flash

This http://kb2.adobe.com/cps/164/tn_16417.html link explains it with details

Answer (score 1):

You can use `FlashVars` to pass the parameters along to your AS classes in your application. See this article - http://kb2.adobe.com/cps/164/tn_16417.html - on working with FlashVars.